# Python: Numpy slices not comparing / broadcasting together. [x:y] vs [0: y-x] Claiming different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, slice, array-broadcasting, advanced-indexing

I am comparing two slices of the same array. The two slices are the same, except they are offset in the [1] axis. I compare these two slices and return their minimum repeatedly in a while loop.

**My expectation:** The size of the arrays stay the same relative to each other, shrinking by the value of "offset"

**What happens instead:** One of the arrays shrinks in size relative to the other in the second iteration, shrinking by more than the value of "offset"

As I am using the same offset value to compare them, and as (x-y) - 0 = x - (0 + y), these values must be the same. For the first iteration, they are the same, but for the second iteration, they are not, as you can see from the printed output.

I thought that the problem might be related to pass-by-value issues, so I tried using copy.deepcopy, but this is not correcting the problem either. I also thought there might be a quirk in indexing overflow indices, so I set height and width to one less, just in case, but that produced no effect either. I am wondering if i might have a fundamental misunderstanding of how slicing or advanced indexing works.

Here is the printed output:

```
Slice 1: offset value: 1    height, width: 999 1332
Slice 2: offset value: 1    height, width: 999 1332
Slice 1: offset value: 2    height, width: 999 1331
Slice 2: offset value: 2    height, width: 999 1330
```

Here is the error I get, It triggers on the second iteration of the while loop:

```
    image = np.minimum(slice1, slice2)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (999,1331) (999,1330)
```

Here is my code:

```
def horizontal_smear(image, distance):

    height = len(image) - 1
    width  = len(image[0] - 1)
    offset = 1

    while offset < distance /2:

        slice1 = copy.deepcopy(image[0 : height, 0 : (width - offset)])
        print ("Slice 1: offset value:", offset, "   height, width:", len(slice1), len(slice1[0]))        
        slice2 = copy.deepcopy(image[0 : height, offset : width])
        print ("Slice 2: offset value:", offset, "   height, width:", len(slice2), len(slice2[0]))        

        image = np.minimum(slice1, slice2)
        offset *= 2

    return image
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolves the coding error preventing the function from working properly. It does not explain the underlying mechanism of the error:

in the while loop, image shrinks, so that each subsequent copy of slice1 and slice2 has less source data to draw from, but "height" and "width" remain fixed. As slice 2 is further to the right than slice 1, this pushes it out of indexing range. (This likely has something to do with why its indices shrink, but I do not know how numpy handles out-of-range data.)

Changing the line `image = np.minimum(slice1, slice2)` to

`image[0:height, 0:(width - offset)] = np.minimum(slice1, slice2)` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your second slice runs off the end of the shrunken `image` array. The problem is that your code is rebinding `image` to successively smaller arrays, but your `width` variable remains the same (one less than the original size). You probably need to be updating `width` inside the loop.

```
# move the width line from here
offset = 1

while offset < distance /2:
    width = len(image[0] - 1)   # to here

    ...
```

Some more detail on why your code wound up with the exact error it did: When you slice off the end of a container in Python (including Numpy arrays, which don't always behave the same as other types), you get a smaller result than you might have been expecting, and no error. Here's an example with lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[0:2] # len(b) is 2
c = a[2:4] # len(c) is unexpectedly 1!
```

The slice to make `c` results in a one-element list because there are no more elements after index 2, even though the slice notation might have lead you to expect the result to have two elements (from indexes 2-3).